# Error "Se espera el nombre del parámetro seguido de ':'"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit-3

estoy siguiendo un tutorial sobre desarrollo de apps en ios con swift pero tengo un problema al declarar la siguiente funcion para un viewController:

```
func setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4], animated: true)
```

Xcode me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Expected parameter name followed by ':'
Expected parameter type following ':'
```

Al tratar de compilar muestra "Build Failed", no logro ver cual es el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores son claros. Al declara una función necesitas especificar un nombre y un tipo del parámetro:

```
func miFuncion(paramInt: Int, paramString: String) { }
```

El llamado a esa función sería:

```
miFuncion(paramInt: 10, paramString: "Diez")
```

Puedes obviar el nombre en el llamado de la función anteponiendo `_` en cada parámetro:

```
miFuncion(_ paramInt: Int, _ paramString: String)
```

El llamado a esa función quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
miFuncion(10, "Diez")
```

En el caso de los parámetros de la pregunta, según la documentación de Apple debe ser declarada así:

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?,
           animated: Bool)
```

Este es el [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers) de la documentación de Apple sobre esa función.