# Confuso con los : y =

Tags: swift

Estoy estos días aprendiendo Swift, y nunca sé cuándo hay que usar `:` y cuándo `=` ya que las dos se pueden usar para inicializar una variable si no me equivoco.

Comment: Tampoco se por que por ejemplo, en TextField(“Nombre”, text: $tuNombre) el primer argumento se pone y ya esta y en el segundo hay que poner text:

Comment: No conozco mucho de swift pues apenas he hecho un hello world con él, pero las dos no inicializan variables. El `:` al igual que en typescript por ejemplo, se usa para TIPAR una variable, indicar de qué tipo va a ser: private nombre: String = "Alex"` estás declarando la variable de tipo String, y asingándole el valor "Alex". En cuanto a por qué se usa así en el constructor... Un objeto de tipo `TextField` puede recibir múltiples parámetros al inicializarlo, así que si no los utilizas todos necesitas indicar qué es cada cosa, por eso se usa el `text: $nombre`.

Comment: Puedes revisar mi respuesta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538689/error-se-espera-el-nombre-del-parámetro-seguido-de/538822#538822) sobre los nombres de los argumentos en las funciones.

Answer (score 2):

**El simbolo ":"**, como en otros lenguajes (como Kotlin), es usado para declarar el tipo de datos, por ejemplo:

```
var myVar: Int //Declara variable tipo entera
var myMensaje : String //Declara variable tipo cadena
```

por lo tanto **el simbolo ":", no se usa para inicializar una variable, se usa para declarar su tipo.**

se recomienda usar para definir el tipo de la variable, ya que swift es un lenguaje seguro para tipos (Type Safe Language)

> [Swift es un lenguaje de tipo seguro](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#:%7E:text=Swift%20is%20a%20type%2Dsafe,it%20an%20Int%20by%20mistake.), lo que significa que el lenguaje
> lo ayuda a tener claro los tipos de valores con los que puede trabajar
> su código. Si parte de su código requiere una Cadena, la seguridad de
> tipo le impide pasarle un Int por error. Del mismo modo, la seguridad
> de tipos le impide pasar accidentalmente una cadena opcional a un
> fragmento de código que requiere una cadena no opcional. La seguridad
> de tipos le ayuda a detectar y corregir errores lo antes posible en el
> proceso de desarrollo.

**El símbolo (operador) "="** es un [operador de asignación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols), y este si puede ser usado para inicializar una variable, puesto que se utiliza para especificar valores predeterminados.

```
var myVar: Int = 12 //Declara variable tipo entera y la inicializa
var myMensaje : String = "Hola Alex" //Declara variable tipo cadena y la inicializa
```

Answer (score 1):

Regularmente `:` is para establecer el tipo y `=` es para darle valor

```
let nombre: Tipo = Valor
```

En diccionarios el `:` separa la llave y el valor `[Llave : Valor]`